# Using vue-grid-layout with Sails.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sails.js

I'm a little new to both Vue and Sails.js, but would anyone have any idea how to use vue-grid-layout in a Sails.js app? I'm having a hell of a time.

I've installed vue-grid-layout via NPM and that is as far as I can get. I've read a bit about including npm modules in Sails, ex: http://ash.zi.vc/sails/2016/02/02/including-client-side-node-modules-in-my-sails-application/ but I'm afraid I'm still a bit lost.

I have a test app working fine as a standalone Vue app containing a `dashboard.html` file with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/box-sizing.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 class="page-title">Dashboard</h2>
    <div id="app" style="width: 100%;">
      <!--<pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>-->
      <div>
        <div class="layoutJSON">
          Displayed as <code>[x, y, w, h]</code>:
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="layoutItem" v-for="item in layout">
              <b>{{item.i}}</b>: [{{item.x}}, {{item.y}}, {{item.w}},
              {{item.h}}]
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <button @click="addItem">Add Box</button>
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="draggable" /> Draggable
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="resizable" /> Resizable
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="responsive" /> Responsive
        <br />
        <grid-layout
          :layout.sync="layout"
          :col-num="12"
          :row-height="30"
          :is-draggable="draggable"
          :is-resizable="resizable"
          :vertical-compact="true"
          :use-css-transforms="true"
          :responsive="responsive"
          :breakpoints="{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }"
          :cols="{ lg: 12, md: 12, sm: 12, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }"
        >
          <grid-item
            v-for="item in layout"
            :x="item.x"
            :y="item.y"
            :w="item.w"
            :h="item.h"
            :i="item.i"
            :key="item.i"
          >
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="card-top-bar w-clearfix">
                <div class="card-title"><p>{{item.cardTitle}}</p></div>
                <a @click="removeItem(item.i)" href="#"
                  >
                  <div class="settingsLink">
                    <img
                      src="images/settings-24px.svg"
                      width="20"
                      alt=""
                    /></div
                ></a>
              </div>
              <div class="reading-value">{{item.reading}}</div>
              <div class="reading-label">{{item.readingLabel}}</div>
            </div>
          </grid-item>
        </grid-layout>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/vue-grid-layout.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dashboard.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the `dashboard.js` code:

```
var testLayout = [
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 8,
    h: 14,
    i: "1",
    cardTitle: "Title 1",
    reading: "74.6",
    readingLabel: "Reading 1",
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 14,
    w: 4,
    h: 5,
    i: "2",
    cardTitle: "Title 2",
    reading: "4.5",
    readingLabel: "Reading 2",
  },
  {
    x: 4,
    y: 14,
    w: 4,
    h: 5,
    i: "3",
    cardTitle: "Title 3",
    reading: "39.5",
    readingLabel: "Reading 3",
  },
  {
    x: 8,
    y: 14,
    w: 4,
    h: 5,
    i: "4",
    cardTitle: "Title 4",
    reading: "7.7",
    readingLabel: "Reading 4",
  },
  {
    x: 8,
    y: 0,
    w: 4,
    h: 9,
    i: "5",
    cardTitle: "Title 5",
    reading: "7.777",
    readingLabel: "Reading 5",
  },
  {
    x: 8,
    y: 9,
    w: 4,
    h: 5,
    i: "6",
    cardTitle: "Title 6",
    reading: "79%",
    readingLabel: "Reading 6",
  },
];

// var GridLayout = VueGridLayout.GridLayout;
// var GridItem = VueGridLayout.GridItem;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  // components: {
  //     "GridLayout": GridLayout,
  //     "GridItem": GridItem
  // },
  data: {
    layout: testLayout,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    responsive: true,
    index: 0,
  },
  
      mounted: function () {
          this.index = this.layout.length;
      },
      methods: {
          addItem: function () {
      // Add a new item. It must have a unique key!
          this.layout.push({
            x: (this.layout.length * 4) % (this.colNum || 12),
            y: this.layout.length + (this.colNum || 12), // puts it at the bottom
            w: 4,
            h: 5,
            i: this.index,
            cardTitle: "Untitled",
            reading: "N/A",
            readingLabel: ""
          });
          // Increment the counter to ensure key is always unique.
          this.index++;
        },
        removeItem: function (val) {
          this.layout = this.layout.filter((item) => item.i !== val);
        },
      }
  
});
```

Any insight greatly appreciated.
View-grid-layout [instructions here](https://jbaysolutions.github.io/vue-grid-layout/guide/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by including `<script src="/vue-grid-layout.umd.min.js"></script>` in the ejs page file, and pull data from the database. It'll work for now but I'd like to figure out how to include the node module in the app instead.